Laravel Filepond, Restore File when got window reload or user closes Browser
Im working on a laravel project and I integrated filepond for my file uploads, after searching a lot on how to make the restore function work and nothing seem to help me out, here I am, If any body can help out in this regard please do. so I have tried many ways on how I can restore the user uploaded after a window reload or when the user closes the browser without finishing the form. this is what I got so far
             // Filepond javascript
             FilePond.setOptions({
                chunkUploads: true,
                server: {
                    process: "{{ route('file.store') }}",
                    revert: "{{ route('file.delete') }}",
                    restore: "{{ route('file.restore') }}",
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}',
                        'Access-Control-Expose-Headers': 'Content-Disposition,',
                    },
                    onload: (response) => {
                        FilePond.setFiles(response);
                        console.log("test");
                    },
                },
                
            });

            const inputFile = document.querySelector("#attachment");
            const pond = FilePond.create(inputFile, {
                allowMultiple: true,
                acceptedFileTypes: [
                        "image/jpeg",
                        "image/png",
                        "image/jiff",
                        "application/pdf",
                        "application/msword",
                        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document",
                    ],
                    fileValidateTypeDetectType: (source, type) =>
                    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                        resolve(type);
                        }
                    ),
                },
            );

web routes:
    // File Management
    Route::post('file-store', [TemporaryFileController::class, 'store'])->name('file.store');
    Route::delete('file-delete', [TemporaryFileController::class, 'destroy'])->name('file.delete');
    Route::get('file-restore', [TemporaryFileController::class, 'head'])->name('file.restore');

temporaryfilecontroller:
public function restore()
    {
        $temporaryFiles = TemporaryFile::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get();
        if ($temporaryFiles) {
            // Get the file path from the details
            $filePath = $temporaryFiles->folder;
            $fileName = $temporaryFiles->file;

            // Set appropriate headers
            $headers = [
                'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="' . $fileName . '"',
            ];

            // Return the file response
            return response()->file($filePath, $headers);
        } else {
            // If file details are not found, return a 404 response
            abort(404);
        }
    }




so the code above is the current i have. I've tried alot but nothing seem to work. can you help me figure it out and tell me where I did wrong.
